# user story failing to complete JavaScript Calculator

Tags: javascript, math, calculator

I am completing the freecodecamp certificate and I am creating a javaScript Calculator. However, I can't pass all test cases. There is just one that I can't find the way to pass it.

the user story I'm missing is:
If 2 or more operators are entered consecutively, the operation performed should be the last operator entered (excluding the negative (-) sign.

When I operate `5*-5` it outputs `25` instead of `-25`. Actually the `-` never shows up on the screen. Here is the link to my code:

https://codepen.io/santiago28b/pen/bGOpgoW

```
class Calculator{
    constructor(previousOperand,currentOperand){
        this.previousOperand = previousOperand
        this.currentOperand = currentOperand
        this.clear()
        
    }

    clear(){
        this.currentOperand = ''
        this.previousOperand = ''
        this.operation = undefined
        this.updateDisplay();
        console.log('it worked apparently')
    }

    delete(){
        this.currentOperand = this.currentOperand.toString().slice(0,-1)

    }

    appendNumber(number){
        if(number === '.' && this.currentOperand.includes('.')) return
        if (number === '0' && this.currentOperand === '0') return;
        this.currentOperand = this.currentOperand.toString() + number.toString()
    }

    selectOperation(operation){
        if(this.currentOperand === '') return
        if(this.previousOperand !== ''){
            this.compute()
        }
        this.operation = operation
        this.previousOperand = this.currentOperand
        this.currentOperand = ''

    }

    compute(){
        let computation
        const prev = parseFloat(this.previousOperand)
        const current = parseFloat(this.currentOperand)
        if(isNaN(prev)|| isNaN(current)) return
        switch(this.operation){
            case '+':
                computation = prev + current
                break
            case '-':
                computation = prev - current
                break
            case '*':
                computation = prev*current
                break
            case '÷':
                computation = prev/current
                break
            default:
                return
        }
        this.currentOperand = computation
        this.operation = undefined
        this.previousOperand = ''
    }

    updateDisplay(){
        // currentOperand.innerText = this.currentOperand;
        // previousOperand.innerText = this.previousOperand;
        currentOperand.innerText = this.currentOperand === '' ? '0' : this.currentOperand;
    if (this.operation != null) {
        previousOperand.innerText = `${this.previousOperand} ${this.operation}`;
    } else {
        previousOperand.innerText = '';
    }
}
}

const numberButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-number]');
const operationButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-operation]');
const equalsButtons = document.querySelector('[data-equals]');
const deleteButtons = document.querySelector('[data-delete]');
const previousOperand = document.querySelector('[data-previous-operand]');
const currentOperand = document.querySelector('[data-current-operand]');
const allClearButton = document.querySelector('[data-all-clear]');

const calculator = new Calculator(previousOperand,currentOperand);

numberButtons.forEach(button =>{
    button.addEventListener('click',() =>{
        calculator.appendNumber(button.innerText)
        calculator.updateDisplay()
    })
})

operationButtons.forEach(button =>{
    button.addEventListener('click',()=>{
        calculator.selectOperation(button.innerText)
        calculator.updateDisplay()
    })
})

allClearButton.addEventListener('click',() => {
    calculator.clear();
   // calculator.updateDisplay()
})

equalsButtons.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    calculator.compute()
    calculator.updateDisplay()
})

deleteButtons.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    calculator.delete()
    calculator.updateDisplay()
})
```

I tried changing the `selectOperation` method but I was unlucky

Comment: Your `compute` function assumes there are two operands. `-5` does not have two operands, it's a unary operator, even though `3-6`_does_ have two operands. So you're going to have to write some code that can determine whether `-` is the unary or binary operator.